# Right way to handle a checkbox with Angular and Redux (ng-redux TODO app)

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

Basically I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to handle a checkbox using Angular + Redux [(ng-redux)](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux).

I have a list of TODOs and wanna be able to check/uncheck a checkbox (mark a TODO as done/undone).

The app works perfectly but whenever I want to skip/jump my `changeTodoDone action` using [Chrome Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) I'm unable to (diff changes to `(states are equal)` after jump/skip)

This is my template:

```
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="msg" type="text">
  <button (click)="addTodo()">add</button>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let iTodo of iTodos$ | async; let idx = index;">
  <span class="msg">{{iTodo.msg}}</span>
  <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="iTodo.done" (ngModelChange)="changeTodoDone($event, idx)">
  <button (click)="removeTodo(idx)">remove</button>
</div>
```

inside my component.ts file I have:

```
@select() readonly iTodos$: Observable<ITodo[]>;

...

changeTodoDone($event, idx: number) {
  this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.changeTodoDone($event, idx));
}
```

and in my store.ts file I have:

```
function changeTodoDone(ilastState: IAppState, done: boolean, idxTodo: number): IAppState {
  const iTodos = ilastState.iTodos.map((todo, idx) => {
    if (idxTodo === idx) {
      todo.done = done;
    }
    return todo;
  });
  return { iTodos: iTodos };
}

export function rootReducer(lastState: IAppState, action: ITodoAction): IAppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CounterActions.CHANGE_TODO_DONE: return changeTodoDone(lastState, action.done, action.idx);
    case CounterActions.ADD_TODO: return addTodo(lastState, action.text);
    case CounterActions.REMOVE_TODO: return removeTodo(lastState, action.idx);
  }

  // We don't care about any other actions right now.
  return lastState;
}
```

Thanks.